# Touch event missed when clicking on the edge of area

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, touch

When I touch the DIV area on the very edge, it will not fire `touchstart` event, but it will still fire `click` event.

```js
(function(jQ) {
  var button = jQ(".button");
  var label = jQ(".label");
  var filledIn = false;
  button.on("touchstart", function() {
    if (!filledIn) {
      label.text("touched!");
      filledIn = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
       label.text("");
        filledIn = false;
      }, 1000);
    }
  })
  button.on("click", function() {
    if (!filledIn) {
      label.text("clicked!");
      filledIn = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
       label.text("");
        filledIn = false;
      }, 1000);
    }
  })
})($);
```

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  border: 15px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label"></div>
<div class="button">
  Touch me here
</div>
```

Tap with your finger right next to the blue border of the box, and it will fire clicked, but not touched.

Note, it happens to me on Chrome. On Edge, once you enable the touch interface, it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Please do not post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can become dead over time and then your question is meaningless here. The 7th button the toolbar when you are creating a question allows you to insert a "code snippet", which allows us to see and execute your code. I have edited your question to include this.

Comment: Thanks, Scott... I just verified, that even running the snippet here inside SO still demonstrates the problem...

Comment: You have two events listening... What do you think is going to happen? Touch screens trigger both events.

Comment: And that's the problem: it doesn't... Tap somewhere close to the edge of the box. Only `click` triggers, not `touchstart`.

Comment: @TomBurger remove the conditional checks from both events and leave only a console.log(one "touched" and the other "clicked") and you will find that both fire. In your code right now you essentially created a race condition.

Comment: No, there is no race condition -- touchstart should be fired before clicked (and it is sequential, because JS is single-threaded), so if touchstart would be fired, you would never see clicked. But if you tap on the edge of the box, you see clicked, which means touchstart was not fired.